# Cannot implicitly convert type when using generics

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I am trying to set a value on a base class but am getting the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'PersonService'` to
>   `'IMyInterface<IEntity>'`. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

When I try to create my `PersonService()` it does implement `IMyInterface<Person>`. Person implements `IEntity` so I can't work out why it is not working.

```
public interface IEntity { }
public class Person : IEntity { }
public interface IMyInterface<T> where T : IEntity { }
public class PersonService : IMyInterface<Person> { }
public abstract class Model : IEntity
{
    public IMyInterface<IEntity> DataService { get; set; }
}
public class Test : Model
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public Test() : base()
    {
        DataService = new PersonService();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `IMyInterface` is not marked as [covariant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq/).  A `string` is an `object` but a `List<string>` is not a `List<object>` because you can't add an `object` to it.

Answer (score 5):

An `IMyInterface<Person>` isn't necessarily compatible with an `IMyInterface<IEntity>`. What if `IMyInterface` contains an `.Add(T item)` method? If you were allowed to call that through `IMyInterface<IEntity>` for something that's not a `Person`, the collection would end up with an invalid element, violating type safety.

But what if `IMyInterface` contains no such methods, and it's always safe? In that case you can tell the compiler that by using a [covariant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq/) type:

```
public interface IMyInterface<out T> where T : IEntity { }
```

And now your example will compile.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your interface co-variant (if it's possible):

```
public interface IMyInterface<out T> where T : IEntity { }
```

Then you would be able to do:

```
DataService = new PersonService();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `DataService` is expecting an `IMyInterface<IEntity>` not an `IMyInterface<Person>`.

Other answers regarding covariance are a great way to solve this - another is to introduce some generics.

If you change `Model` like this to specify the type of entity

```
public abstract class Model<TEntity> : IEntity 
            where TEntity : IEntity
{
    public IMyInterface<TEntity> DataService { get; set; }
}
```

and `Test` like this:

```
public class Test : Model<Person>
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public Test() : base()
    {
        DataService = new PersonService();
    }
}
```

All works as expected:

http://rextester.com/EVBT53292

Comment: Run that. It will compile, but fail at runtime with an InvalidCastException.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram yes thanks - ive changed this answer quite considerably now.